# Github repository code is not matching live website

Tags: github, repository, github-pages, github-desktop

I've pushed changes to my html file to change a URL, but the changes are not showing up on the live website. I checked the repository and the code is updated with the new URL, but still the live website is not showing the changes (I've tried on new devices/browsers).

I'm using Github pages and Github Desktop to push changes. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the repo was private but needed to be public to update.